# Python code to find a total number of shortest words in a string

Tags: python, string

I am searching for a python code that finds the total number of shortest word in a string. 
For example if the string is "The play 's the thing wherein I'll catch the conscience of the king.” then the result should be "8 short words"

Comment: Can you please a code snippet that shows what you already tried? If you need more information, see [Asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: @Virginia Yes sure, the exact question is as follows

Comment: @Virginia Write a script that reads a typed text, analyzes how many words the text consists of, and prints out the total number of words as well as the number of "short" words of just three letter or less. 

The string is : "The play 's the thing wherein I'll catch the conscience of the king."

string= input("Enter string:")
word=1
for i in string:
    if(i==' '):
        word=word+1
print("Number of words in the string:")
print(word)

Comment: Ah I see. I'm still very new to Python so I'm afraid I can't help you with syntax and such. I do think you need an approach where you first count all the words in the string. Your second step could be to iterate over all the found words and check if their length is three letters or less. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

`input_string = "The play 's the thing wherein I'll catch the conscience of the king."`

To count number of words:
`print(len(input_string.split()))`

Output:
`13`

To count number of words of just three letter or less:
`print(len([x for x in input_string.split() if len(x) <= 3]))`

Output:
`6`

If you want the list of words of just three letter or less, exclude the len() function.
`print([x for x in input_string.split() if len(x) <= 3])`

Output:
`['The', "'s", 'the', 'the', 'of', 'the']`

Comment: Hey 
Is there a way that the code counts "I'll" as two separate words. which makes the number of words to 14 . Also when the code counts the number of words with three letters or less, it can also count "I'll" as two different words which makes the output for the number of words with three letter or less as 8.

Comment: Of course there is a way to do so. It depends on whether "I'll" is the only word that you want considered as two separate words? What bout "You'll" or "We'll"?

Comment: Yes all the words like that should be considered as two separate words. 
can you please share the code for how to do that?

Thanks in advance